# BigQuery: Get field names of a STRUCT

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some data in a STRUCT in BigQuery. Below I have visualised an example of the data as JSON:

```
{ 
  ...
  siblings: {
    david: { a: 1 }
    sarah: { b: 1, c: 1 }
  }
  ...
}
```

I want to produce a field from a query that resembles `["david", "sarah"]`. Essentially I just want to get the keys from the STRUCT (object). Note that every user will have different key names in the siblings STRUCT.

Is this possible in BigQuery?

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0):

Your structs schema must be consistent throughout the table. They can't change keys because they're part of the table schema. To get the keys you simply take a look at the table schema.

If values change, they're probably values in an array - I guess you might have something like this:

```sql
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [STRUCT('david' AS name, 33 as age), ('sarah', 42)] AS siblings
  union all
  SELECT 2, [('ken', 19), ('ryu',21), ('chun li',23)]
)

SELECT * FROM t
```

If you tried to introduce new keys in the second row or within the array, you'd get an error `Array elements of types {...} do not have a common supertype at ...`.

The first element of the above example in json representation looks like this:

```js
{
    "id": "1",
    "siblings": [
      {
        "name": "david",
        "age": "33"
      },
      {
        "name": "sarah",
        "age": "42"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This STRUCT is part of a schema where the type is RECORD in Big Query. Does the same restriction still apply?

Comment: yes, read more here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated RECORD=STRUCT and REPEATED=ARRAY